# VC++-MFC : LoadLibrary returns invalid handle 0x10000000

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, loadlibrary

I am unable to load my test.dll (in VC++ - MFC) using `LoadLibrary()` API. I get error code `126 (Module not found)`using `GetLastError()`.
By dependency walker I have come to know that my test.dll depends on "xerces-c_2_7.dll" and "Xalan-C_1_10.dll". These dlls were already present on the same path as the exe.
Still I am getting the error.
So I tried to load both the above mentioned third party dlls using `LoadLibrary()` which returned handle as `0x10000000`. By `GetLastError()` I am getting

```
error code 6 (Invalid Handle).
```

Can anyone please guide me on why I am getting the Invalid Handle error?

Below is the code snipet:

```
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(_T("Xalan-C_1_10"));
TCHAR szMessage[MAX_PATH];
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS|
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL, GetLastError(),
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL),
    szMessage, MAX_PATH, NULL);
    hLib = LoadLibrary(_T("xerces-c_2_7"));
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS|
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL, GetLastError(),
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL),
    szMessage, MAX_PATH, NULL);
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. According to MSDN, any non-null return value means success, and 0x10000000 is non-null.

Comment: @erikkallen: IIUC, the OP is able to load Xerces and Xalan individually but not the `test.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Distilling your problem, I gather:

- You are able to load Xerces and Xalan individually, but not the test.dll file (which references the other dlls)
- You may be misled by the value `GetLastError()` returns when loading either Xerces or Xalan

Remember that you must call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx) immediately after the `LoadLibrary` call: From MSDN docs:

> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function.

This is most probably a dependency/path resolution issue (i.e. `LoadLibrary` can't find the requested image). So, you have two options:

- Does test.dll/Xerces/Xalan have other dependencies that you have not copied to your executable's folder?
- Put the dll in Windows\System32 folder and try again. If this works, then you can be sure you had hit a path problem. Read the MSDN page on [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) -- it's a bit confusing but has some details that's easy to leave out.
- Use `GetCurrentDirectory` and `SetCurrentDirectory` to switch to and from the application's executing folder and the dll's residing folder
- Specify the full path to the dll in the call to `LoadLibrary`. You may face issues if the path name contains whitespace (this I recall from memory, please check with MSDN).
- Once done, be a good citizen and call `FreeLibrary`!

Answer (score 0):

Is test.dll your DLL or third party DLL?

```
If it is a your DLL,
```

you should be easily able to see the depent DLLs in the code & its exact path.

```
If it is third party DLL,
```

you need to try windows path, program files path, your test DLL path etc... Remember it is only a try.
Sometimes they may refer to the path which is only known to the creator the DLL *if not documented*)

Hope this answer helps!